# How to change coordinates in a conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say I have the (continuous) probability density $p_X(x|Y=y)$, then what is the (discrete) probability mass $P(H(X)=a|H(Y)=b)$, where $H(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside step function? In this case $a,b\in\left\{0,1 \right\} $, so I think that $\int_{-\infty}^{0}p_{X}\left(x|Y=y\right)dx=P\left(H\left(X\right)=0|Y=y\right)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}p_{X}\left(x|Y=y\right)dx=P\left(H\left(X\right)=1|Y=y\right)$, but how do I change the second variable?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that $(H(X), H(Y))$ is discrete and thus does't have a probability density (wrt. the lebesgue measure), only a mass function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just apply the definition of conditional probability, so assuming that $Y$ is also a continuous random variable.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(H(X)=a\mid H(Y)=y) ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(H(X)=a, H(Y)=b)}{\mathsf P(H(Y)=b)} \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\displaystyle\iint_{H(x)=a, H(y)=b} p_{X\mid Y=y}(x)~p_Y(y)\operatorname d (x,y)}{\displaystyle\int_{H(y)=b} p_Y(y)\operatorname d y} \end{align}$$

If however, $Y$ is a discrete random variable:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(H(X)=a\mid H(Y)=y) ~=~& \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{y: H(y)=b}\left(\mathsf P(Y=y)\int_{H(x)=a}  p_{X\mid Y=y}(x)~\operatorname d x\right)}{\displaystyle\sum_{y:H(y)=b} \mathsf P(Y=y)} \end{align}$$

Of particular note, we cannot 'change the variable' without knowing the distribution of $Y$.

Also, the event $\{H(Z)=c\}$ is the event $\{Z\geq 0\}$ iff $c=1$ and $\{Z<0\}$ iff $c=0$.

Comment: Absolutely right, many thanks Graham :)